# Confusing Integration Problem, Don't Know Where to Start

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The question is:

If f is continuous and $ \int_0^9 f(x)dx = 16$, find $ \int_0^3 xf(x^2)dx. $

It seems like this isn't too hard of a problem, but we just started studying this sort of integral problem and I honestly don't know where to start.  Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: How familiar are you with changes of variables ?

Comment: If you use $x^2 = t$ change of variable, it transforms to same form as the first.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** let $x=\sqrt{u}$  then you will get what you need. are you able to finish

Comment: Yes I figured it out, thank you for your help!

Comment: @AmandaGuilland you can accept this answer if it helped you greatly.